# signal clicked works only with static methods

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5, I'm trying to create an application that involves a QPushButton. Now, when the user clicks this button, a function is supposed to be executed.

When I try to use `button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked_slot)` it works as expected only and only if `button_clicked_slot()` is a static method, i.e. doesn't take `self` as an argument. In case it is a non-static method, the function isn't executed when the button is clicked.

I've tried various similar answers from StackOver and elsewhere, none of them could solve the problem I'm facing. I'm creating and using this button inside a class, the slot function is a method of this same class. I've tried to make the class inherit from QWidget and QObject, neither of those solutions worked. It always seems to boil down to using a staticmethod.

The entire code would be very big, however, here is an over-simplified code snippet with the exact same

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class activity(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('test button')
        button.clicked.connect(self.temp_print)
        window.setCentralWidget(button)

        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    @staticmethod
    def temp_print():
        print('Reached here')

activity()
```

In the above code, the method `temp_print()` is executed whenever the button is clicked (because it is a staticmethod). However, if I rewrite the function as:

```
    def temp_print(self):
        print('Reached here')
```

And suddenly, this function is never executed regardless of how many times I click the button.

In several other code snippets and the official documentation, I've seen a non-static function being used as a slot and things seem to be going smoothly for them. The code snippet I shared above is an overly-simplified version of the problem that I'm facing.

And yes, in the code that I shared above, I don't need the `self` parameter inside the function and thus should be able to use a static method too. However, like I mentioned, this is a simplified version of the code I'm using (my actual code is over 500+ lines and thus it would be very stupid to paste the whole thing here), but, in my actual code, I am using the `self` parameter and thus need a non-static function to be used as the slot for click events.

Comment: the tags have a specific section, avoid placing them unnecessarily in the titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static methods can be invoked without the need to have an instance unlike the methods of the class that need the object to be created.

In your example, `app.exec_()` prevents the constructor from running, so the other methods of the class such as `temp_print` can not be called.

So there are 2 possible solutions:

- Use a lambda method to invoke temp_print:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Activity:
    def __init__(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("test button")
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.temp_print())
        window.setCentralWidget(button)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def temp_print(self):
        print("Reached here")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Activity()
```

- Let the object finish building:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Activity:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m_app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("test button")
        button.clicked.connect(self.temp_print)
        self.window.setCentralWidget(button)
        self.window.show()

    def temp_print(self):
        print("Reached here")

    def run(self):
        return self.m_app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Activity()
    sys.exit(a.run())
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. The lambda solution works elegantly... Also, when you said: 'In your example, app.exec_() prevents the constructor from running, so the other methods of the class such as temp_print can not be called', can you explain how does `app.exec_()` prevent the constructor of some other class from running?

Comment: Also, in the second solution in which you used `a.run()`, I'm getting an error that says: 'Class Activity has no method run()', could it be that the class `Activity` is supposed to inherit from some other class that has the `run()` method?

Comment: @PriyanshBhatt 1) app.exec_() does not let the following lines run, try adding a print after that line. 2) have you tested the code I have provided ?, IMHO you are testing in your code without analyzing my response, if you observe I have created a method run.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I didn't see the `run()` method that you created. Now both the solutions are working. Thanks a lot for your help once again!